# Increment And Decrement is Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am Making a Python Guessing Game Program And I am Not Able to Decrement a Value. Here Is My Program:

```
import random as rand

print('\t\t\tGuess Game\n')
print('Enter a Number Between 1 and 20')

while True:

    a = rand.randint(1, 20)

    for i in range(1, 5):
        guess = 0

        guess = int(input('Enter a Number : '))

        if guess == a:
            print('You Are Right\n')
            break

        if guess == 0 or guess < 0:
            print('Please Enter a Positive Integer\n')
            i -= 1
            continue

        if guess > 20:
            print('Please Enter a Reasonable Number\n')
            i -= 1
            continue

        if guess > a:
            if guess <= (a + 5):
                print('Your Number is Little High\n')

            else:
                print('Your Number is Too High\n')

        if guess < a:
            if guess >= (a - 5):
                print('Your Number is Little Low\n')

            else:
                print('Your Number is Too Low\n')

    if guess != a:
        print('My Number Was %s. Please try The Program Again If You Like\n' % a)

    play = str(input('Do You Want to play Again? '))
    play.lower()
    if play.startswith('y'):
        continue

    elif play.startswith('n'):
        break

    else:
        while play is not ((play.startswith('y') and play.endswith('s')) or play == 'y') or ((play.startswith('n') and play.endswith('o')) or play == 'n'):
            play = input('Please Enter a Yes or No')
```

i -= 1 is not Working.

Thanks.

Edit
This is Taking 7 guesses while negative integer is used

import random as rand

i = 5 # Number of guesses
a = rand.randint(1, 20)

while i > 0:
    guess = int(input())

```
if guess == a:
    print("You won!")
    break

if guess == 0:
    i = i + 1
    continue

i = i - 1
```

Comment: Why do you want to decrement `i`?

Comment: To Give Them Another Chance As They Wrongly Entered a Number

Comment: You need a `while` loop because your changes to `i` get overwritten when the loop repeats.

Comment: Can you Please Explain It?

Comment: Try yourselves with a simple `for` loop with range(1, 5), print counter and decrement counter within loop. Then implement the same with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for loop, `i` is set on each iteration. So, if you subtract one from the `i` variable, it will simply be set back to what it should be (going from 5 down to 1). To make your loop run until the player runs out of guesses:

```
i = 5 # Number of guesses
while i > 0:
    # Do your game loop here. Subtract from i to lose a guess.

    if guess == a:
        print("You won!")
        break
```

If the player has guessed correctly, "You won!" will be printed and the loop will end. If the player has ran out of guesses, the loop will also end - but without printing a message.

If you want to check whether the player won, just do `i > 0`. This will be true if the player won, as there will still be some guesses remaining.